# Can this function be integrable?

Tags: integration

Let $V: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be such that $V(x) \to \infty$ when $|x| \to \infty$ and $e^{-V}$ is integrable. Can

$$ f(x) := e^{-V(x)}\int_0^x e^{V(y)} \, \mathrm d y $$

be in $L^1(\mathbb R)$? If it can, are there conditions on $V$ under which $f(x)$ is guaranteed not to be in $L^1(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Riemann integrable ? What is the area of integration ?

Comment: You are using the same variable ($x$) as both a free variable and a bound variable (variable of integration). I assume that you mean
$$f(x) := e^{-V(x)}\int_0^x e^{V(y)} \, \mathrm d y$$

Comment: @openspace. I assume that the region of integration is all of $\mathbb R,$ i.e. it's known that $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-V(x)} \, \mathrm d x < \infty$ and it is asked whether it's possible that also $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \, \mathrm d x < \infty.$

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, that is what I meant, thank you. I edited accordingly.

Comment: Something like $V(x) = x^4$ should be an example where $f \in L^1$, I think.

Comment: Please excuse my notation ignorance, but what precisely is meant by $L^1(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you, but I don't really see why... Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

An example with closed-form integrals, but $V(0)=-\infty$.
$$
V(x) = x^4+\log(|x|^3)
$$
works.  We have
$$
e^{V(y)} = |y|^3 e^{y^4};\quad e^{-V(x)} = \frac{e^{-x^4}}{|x|^3}
$$
For $x>0$,
$$
\int_0^x V(y)\;dy = \int_0^x y^3 e^{y^4}\;dy =
\frac{e^{y^4}}{4}\bigg\vert_0^x
= \frac{e^{x^4}-1}{4} > 0
\\
f(x) = \frac{e^{-x^4}}{x^3}\;\frac{e^{x^4}-1}{4} = \frac{1-e^{-x^4}}{4x^3} > 0
$$
and similarly for $x<0$,
$$
f(x) = \frac{-1+e^{-x^4}}{4x^3} > 0
$$
And finally
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|\;dx = 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-x^4}}{4x^3}\;dx < +\infty
$$
so that $f \in L_1(\mathbb R)$.

**remark**
I expect $V(x) = x^4$ similarly yields $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.  But the integral has no nice closed form, meaning that it will require more estimates.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that $e^{-V}$ is not integrable in this case (problem at 0...)?